# Make a 2D sprite from an object's shape

Tags: conversion

This involves using GIMP to get the shape of objects from Blender. How do I get the shapes of my objects, as seen from the camera view, and make them a single colour, with an invisible background? Is there a way to do this with total accuracy, and possibly as a vector image?

Basically, how do you do the computer version of tracing an object from a photo and colouring it in, all one colour, (with no outline afterwards), but with complete precision.

So, a blue vase, seen from an angle, would turn into something like this, but with an invisible background, not so pixelated and in GIMP instead of paint:
[image]

I'd rather not share my work (which is on my desktop PC, which has a broken internet connection) and have my idea stolen, so I shouldn't provide screenshots of it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Scene" tab go to "Passes" and enable "Object Index". Then select the object you want and go to the "Object" tab. Under "Relations" you will find the "Pass Index". Give it a value, example: 1. 
Then go to the compositor and add an ID mask node and a File output node like this:[image]

Set the ID mask node to whatever your object's index is example: 1.
You will get a Black and white image of the silhouette of the object.
Make sure to have a decent resolution so that your image is not pixelated. 
Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In blender internal, you can check "shadeless" in the material.